# Google Earth Engine python

Tags: python, google-maps, qgis, google-earth-engine

I am trying to import nighttime light data on qgis and I keep getting invalid syntax at the last line of my code (`Map. centerObject(sydney, 5)`)

Here is my code

```py
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

sydney_shp_path = ('Users/macbookpro/Downloads/OpenNightLights-master 2/onl/tutorials/files/city_of_sydney_shapefile')

night_img = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG").filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31').select('avg_rad')

NL_mean = night_img.mean()


nightclass = NL_mean.gt(5).add(NL_mean.gt(50)).add(NL_mean.gt(100))
nightclass = nightclass.updateMask(nightclass.neq(0))

Map.addLayer(nightclass.clip(sydney), ({'min':1, 'max':100}, 'VIIRS 2018', 'Nightlight')
Map.centerObject(sydney, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method Map.addLayer is not closed properly.
I am guessing method takes two parameters one return value of clip and another tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Set center of map Map.setCentre()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).